# Loop over a each value wrapped up by listagg

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with a column named `column_names` and for each row it has a list of column names separated by a comma, for example:

| table | column_names |
| --- | --- |
| some | DEPOSITS_COUNT,DEPOSITS |

I want to iterate over each named string in column names, here is what I have tried:

```
DECLARE
  deposits VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
   FOR DEPO IN ( SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (
   column_names, '[^,]+') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" INTO deposits
 FROM REFERENCE_TEST )
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (DEPO.deposits);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

I used `DECLARE` because I kept getting an error that `DEPO` was not declaring something.

The error I get:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 8, column 34:
PLS-00302: component 'DEPOSITS' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 8, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Don't use listagg to store or materialise data? It's a significant anti-pattern. [is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `SELECT ... INTO ...` inside a cursor:

```sql
BEGIN
   FOR DEPO IN (
     SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (column_names, '[^,]+') AS REGEXPR_SUBSTR
     FROM   REFERENCE_TEST
   )
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (DEPO.REGEXPR_SUBSTR);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which will get you the first value in each row.

So, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE REFERENCE_TEST ("TABLE", column_names) AS
SELECT 'some', 'DEPOSITS_COUNT,DEPOSITS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'numbers', 'ONE,TWO,THREE' FROM DUAL;
```

It outputs:

```
DEPOSITS_COUNT
ONE
```

---

If you want all the values then you need to use a row-generator and split the string. You can do that using a recursive sub-query factoring clause and simple string functions (which is much faster than regular expressions):

```sql
BEGIN
   FOR DEPO IN (
     WITH bounds (column_names, spos, epos) AS (
       SELECT column_names,
              1,
              INSTR(column_names, ',', 1)
       FROM   reference_test
     UNION ALL
       SELECT column_names,
              epos + 1,
              INSTR(column_names, ',', epos + 1)
       FROM   bounds
       WHERE  epos > 0
     )
     SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY column_names SET order_id
     SELECT CASE epos
            WHEN 0
            THEN SUBSTR(column_names, spos)
            ELSE SUBSTR(column_names, spos, epos - spos)
            END AS name
     FROM   bounds
   )
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (DEPO.name);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

```
DEPOSITS_COUNT
DEPOSITS
ONE
TWO
THREE
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kiNujYDI)

Comment: Ah I see, so I have to reference `REGEXPR_SUBSTR`, makes sense as I saw something similar in another example. However, how do I go about returning all values and not just first?

Comment: Very helpful! I will study this, thank you :)